# SAXBuilder().build(InputStream) - does this read entire file into memory?

Tags: java, xml, sax, jdom

Reading the docs, this is the method used in all the examples I've seen:

(Version of `org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder` is `jdom-1.1.jar`)

```
Document doc = new SAXBuilder().build(is);
Element root = doc.getRootElement();
Element child = root.getChild("someChildElement");
...
```

where `is` is an `InputStream` variable.

I'm wondering, since this is a SAX builder (as opposed to a DOM builder), does the entire inputstream get read into the document object with the build method?  Or is it working off a lazy load and as long as I request elements with `Element.getChildren()` or similar functions (stemming from the root node) that are forward-only through the document, then the builder automatically takes care of loading chunks of the stream for me?

I need to be sure I'm not loading the whole file into memory.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: If you can access elements by digging from the root, odds are that the whole document is loaded in memory. If you want to have more precisions, please specify the package of `SAXBuilder`

Comment: Thanks david, I edited the question to reflect that the version of org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder is jdom-1.1.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOM parser similarly to the JDom parser loads the whole XML resource in memory to provide you a `Document` instance allowing to navigate in the elements of the XML.
Some references [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/when.html) :

> the DOM standard is a codified standard for an in-memory document
>   model.

And [here](http://www.jdom.org/docs/faq.html) :

> JDOM works on the logical in-memory XML tree,

Both DOM and JDom use the SAX parser internally to read the XML resource but they use it only to store the whole content in the `Document` instance that they return. Indeed, with Dom and JDom, the client never needs to provide a handler to intercept events triggered by the SAX parser.

Note that both  DOM and JDom don't have any obligation to use SAX internally.
They use them mainly as the SAX standard is already there and so it makes sense to use it for reporting errors.

---

> *I need to be sure I'm not loading the whole file into memory.*

You have two programming models to work with XML: streaming and the document object model (DOM).
You are looking for the first one.

So use the [SAX parser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) by providing your handler to handle events generated by the SAX parser (`startDocument()`, `startElement()`, and so for) or as alternative look at a more user friendly API : [STAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/why.html) (Streaming API for XML) :

> As an API in the JAXP family, StAX can be compared, among other APIs,
>   to SAX, TrAX, and JDOM. **Of the latter two, StAX is not as powerful or
>   flexible as TrAX or JDOM, but neither does it require as much memory
>   or processor load to be useful, and StAX can, in many cases,
>   outperform the DOM-based API**s. The same arguments outlined above,
>   weighing the cost/benefits of the DOM model versus the streaming
>   model, apply here.

Answer (score 1):

It eagerly parses the whole file to build the in-memory representation (i.e. `Document`) of the XML file.

If you want to be absolutely certain of that, you can go through the source on [`GitHub`](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom). More importantly the following classes: [`SAXBuilder`](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/jdom-1.1/core/src/java/org/jdom/input/SAXBuilder.java), [`SAXHandler`](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/jdom-1.1/core/src/java/org/jdom/input/SAXHandler.java), and [`Document`](https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/jdom-1.1/core/src/java/org/jdom/Document.java).